# how to print the third column of the file in java

Tags: java

My file contains data which is output of Treetagger

```
    big  JJ big

    nice JJ nice

    full JJ full

    big  JJ big

   best JJS good
```

Here is my code

```
    File f = new File(n[x]);
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(f));
    String s;
    String filedata = "  ";
    while ((s = br.readLine()) != null) {
        filedata += s + " ";
    }

    StringTokenizer stk = new StringTokenizer(filedata, " ");
    while (stk.hasMoreTokens()) {
        String token = stk.nextToken("JJ");
        String[] to = token.split(" ", 2);
        String ft = to[1];
        a.write(ft);
    }
```

The third column is the stemmed words. how to print it?

Comment: `String[] to=token.split(" ",2);` You limit the number of splits to 2, you should update this to 3 or leave the second argument out. After that you can get the third value using to[2]

Comment: Don't use StringTokenizer. It is deprecated. You can use split for string.

Comment: May be the delimeter you are using is to append the string is actually not recomendded I guess may be use `|` and then split string as `|` delimeter

Comment: @pyerwin it doesnt work

Answer (score 1):

Here the code:

```
String[] splitdata = filedata.split(" ");

String thirdcol = splitdata[2];

System.out.println(thirdcol);
```

Hope it will help you.

Comment: Isn't `splitdata[2]` the *third* column?

Comment: splitdata[0] is the first column but [3] is out of b bound

Answer (score 0):

`String.split` method can be used to break up a string into its basic tokens, and take the third one:

```
String[] result = filedata.split(" ");
String col3 = result[2];
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope it will help

```
File f=new File(n[x]);
     BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(f));
     String s;
     while((s=br.readLine())!=null){

String test = s.replace(" ","");

String[] test2 = test.split("JJ");

String test3 = test2[1];

System.out.println(test3);
}
```